# Powershell JSON to CSV / XLSX

Tags: json, powershell, csv, xlsx

Есть JSON файл со следующей структурой:

```
{
  "itemList": [
    {
      "itemNumber": "100000074",
      "itemProp": [
        {
          "propOne": 0,
          "propTwo": "2019-10-15T18:04:14",
          "propThree": 1,
        }
      ],
      "total": {
        "propOne": 0,
        "propTwo": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "propThree": 3,
      }
    },
    {
      "itemNumber": "100090021",
      "itemProp": [
        {
          "propOne": 0,
          "propTwo": "2019-10-15T11:53:59",
          "propThree": 7,
        }
      ],
      "total": {
        "propOne": 0,
        "propTwo": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "propThree": 0,
      }
    },
    {
      "itemNumber": "100000391",
      "itemProp": [
        {
          "propOne": 0,
          "propTwo": "2019-10-15T14:33:03",
          "propThree": 4,
        },
        {
          "propOne": 0,
          "propTwo": "2019-10-15T14:38:15",
          "propThree": 12,
        }
      ],
      "total": {
        "propOne": 0,
        "propTwo": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
        "propThree": 0,
      }
    }    
  ],
  "total": {
    "propOne": 0,
    "propTwo": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "propThree": 0,
  }
}
```

При помощи скрипта:

```
    $JSON = (Get-Content "C:\TEMP\file.json" | ConvertFrom-Json).itemList
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty itemProp
    $JSON
```

Получаю:

```
itemNumber itemProp                                                                                                          total
---------- --------                                                                                                          -----
100000074  {@{propOne=0; propTwo=15.10.2019 18:04:14; propThree=1}}                                                          @{propOne=…
100090021  {@{propOne=0; propTwo=15.10.2019 11:53:59; propThree=7}}                                                          @{propOne=…
100000391  {@{propOne=0; propTwo=15.10.2019 14:33:03; propThree=4}, @{propOne=0; propTwo=15.10.2019 14:38:15; propThree=12}} @{propOne=…
```

Нужно получить:

[image: Needed result]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно разобрать этот JSON на строки при помощи Powershell, учитывая, что вхождений itemProp в каждом из itemNumber может быть от 1 и более (как, например, 100000391)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение в лоб:

```
$arr = ($json = Get-Content C:\temp\file.json | ConvertFrom-Json).itemList
$json = $json.total
(([PSCustomObject[]](0..($arr.Length - 1)).ForEach{
  $a, $b, $c = $arr[$_].itemNumber, $arr[$_].itemProp, $arr[$_].total
  while ($b) {
    .({
      [PSCustomObject]@{
        itemNumber = $a
        propOne = $b.propOne
        propTwo = $b.propTwo.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')
        propThree = $b.propThree
      }
    },{
      for ($i = 0; $i -lt $b.Length; $i++) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
          itemNumber = ($null, $a)[$i -eq 0]
          propOne = $b[$i].propOne
          propTwo = $b[$i].propTwo.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')
          propThree = $b[$i].propThree
        }
      }
    })[$b.propOne -is [Array]]
    $b, $a, $c = $c, $null, $null
  }
}) + [PSCustomObject]@{
  itemNumber = $null
  propOne = $json.propOne
  propTwo = $json.propTwo.ToString('yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss')
  propThree = $json.propThree
}) | ConvertTo-Csv
```

Итог:

```
"itemNumber","propOne","propTwo","propThree"
"100000074","0","2019-10-15T06:04:14","1"
,"0","0001-01-01T12:00:00","3"
"100090021","0","2019-10-15T11:53:59","7"
,"0","0001-01-01T12:00:00","0"
"100000391","0","2019-10-15T02:33:03","4"
,"0","2019-10-15T02:38:15","12"
,"0","0001-01-01T12:00:00","0"
,"0","0001-01-01T12:00:00","0"
```